# cmake opencv3 with python2 on ubuntu get ImportError multiarray.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct

Tags: ubuntu, numpy, cmake, opencv3.0

I tried to use `cmake-gui` to build opencv3 for python2.7 on ubuntu. I have my `numpy(1.8.2)` installed by `pip` (actually, I also tried with `apt-get` but error still existed). Every time I use `cmake-gui` to `Configure` it throws me that:

```
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 20, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt_pkg.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct**strong text**
```

It seems to be something wrong with `_Py_ZeroStruct`. I have tried to reinstall the `numpy`, but it didn't work.

I also tried to ignore this error and keep `make && sudo make install` and the result was I can have my OpenCV3 installed correctly but I cannot use `cv2` of python(no module named `cv2`).
Thus I believe this error is the key issue that I have to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

I should make sure that none of `dist-package` or `site-package` paths are in the `$PYTHONPATH`